# Who's at fault with this error concerning csquotes and LuaLaTeX?

Tags: errors, luatex, csquotes

I ran into this with the package `lilyglyphs` but I'm not sure whose fault this error is.

When I compile the following with `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\EnableQuotes
\begin{document}
\directlua{print("hello")}
\end{document}
```

I get an error saying

> ```
> \directlua]:1: unexpected symbol near '\'.
> l.6 \directlua{print("hello")}
> ```

Now suppose that I do not directly write `\directlua` in my document, but I include a package that does it internally. Such as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec, csquotes, lilyglyphs}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\EnableQuotes
\begin{document}
\wholeNote
\end{document}
```

I have no knowledge why compilation fails, because the error now becomes

> ```
> ! Missing number, treated as zero.
> <to be read again>
> \begingroup
> l.7 \end
>       {document}
> ```

From my user point of view I did nothing wrong, because I'm using the public API provided by the packages. The `csquotes` documentation specifically says:

> Note that all characters are automatically checked for validity as they are allocated. This package will reject characters which are unsuitable as active quotes... In sum, the following
>   characters will be considered as reserved by this package:
>
> ```
>  A–Z a–z 0–9 . , ; : ! ? ' - # $ % & ^ _ ` ~ \ @ * { } [ ]
> ```

So my question is **whose fault is this error?**

- My fault, the user's fault, because I should have known (but how?) that even though the quote is not listed as unsuitable in the csquotes manual, it actually is?
- The fault of the implementation or documentation of `csquotes` for failing to mention `"` as unsuitable?
- The fault of the implementation of the `\directlua` command because it doesn't prevent LaTeX catcode changes/active characters from impacting its argument?
- A shortcoming of TeX itself because of its global state based architecture?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your first example and your second are actually quite different errors. The first is your fault (see Davids answer), but the second is a bug in `lilyglyphs` lua code.

But the problem is not the quote in `\directlua`. As the command is defined in `lilyglyphs` the catcode of the " is frozen there and so not problematic.

`lilyglyphs` uses `tex.sprint` to print the char, and the argument contains a `"`. As `tex.sprint` uses by default the current active catcode regime this explodes. You can tell `tex.sprint` to use another catcode table. (I'm not quite sure if `\CatcodeTableLaTeX` I used the best one, but it works):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec, csquotes,lilyglyphs}

%copied from lilyglyphs
\begin{luacode}
documentdata = documentdata or { }

local stringformat = string.format
local texsprint = tex.sprint
local slot_of_name = luaotfload.aux.slot_of_name

documentdata.fontchar = function (chr)
local chr = slot_of_name(font.current(), chr, false)
if chr and type(chr) == "number" then
texsprint
 (\the\CatcodeTableLaTeX, 
  stringformat ([[\char"%X"]], chr))
end
end
\end{luacode}

\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\EnableQuotes

\begin{document}

\wholeNote

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the package with https://github.com/uliska/lilyglyphs/commit/e04442fd5a1c6c8f1cbd5f813909cd01d2e3efb9

Answer (score 10):

Sorry but since you ask, I'd say it was your fault:-)

Having made a character active you should have known to make it safe before passing to Lua.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\EnableQuotes
\begin{document}
\directlua{print(\string"hello\string")}
\end{document}
```

See Ulrike's answer for the second example.

Comment: Please consider the second part of the question when I use a package, and I have no knowledge of it using `\directlua`. Of course in the first example it's my fault.

Comment: OK, obviously we created the corresponding questions at the same time ;-) The problem is in the package implementation, but I don't know how to fix it. The actual invocation is `\directlua{documentdata.fontchar "#1"}`

Comment: but is there any situation where it is useful to have LaTeX active characters alter the code sent to the Lua interpreter? is this a feature or a bug of LuaTeX?

Comment: @marczellm I was going to answer the second part, but got called to a meeting, will update the answer in a bit, it doesn't seem particularly related to the first part

Comment: @marczellm expansion is a feature that is it a general tex feature that active characters work just like normal macros if `~` is act,ive then `\def~{zzz}` and `\def\foo{zzz}` are essentially the same and you would expect `\directlua{~}` and `\directlua{\foo}` to be the same, as they are.

Comment: @marczellm added some words about the second example

Comment: The problem is not the point where " is made active. You get the same problem if you do remove csquotes and add  `\catcode`\"=13 \def"{XXXXX}` in the document body.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer the added text is nonsense, just editing...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer better?

Comment: Yes ;-). Is `\the\CatcodeTableLaTeX` the correct way to enter the table number?

Comment: yes I think that's best way, conventions around catcode tables are still a bit untested, so currently if it works it is the best way!