# csquotes conflicts with quotation marks in Lua code

Tags: luatex, csquotes

I received an [issue report](https://github.com/uliska/lilyglyphs/issues/94) for my [lilyglyphs](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/lilyglyphs) package. Certain commands in my package fail when the following code is compiled with LuaLaTeX (XeLaTeX works fine):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec, csquotes, lilyglyphs}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\EnableQuotes

\begin{document}
\wholeNote
\end{document}
```

Upon investigation I found that there *are* some quotation marks in the package code, and I assume this is the culprit:

```
\ifluatex
\def\lilyGetGlyph#1{\directlua{documentdata.fontchar "#1"}}
\fi
```

(For context: this can be found here: https://github.com/uliska/lilyglyphs/blob/master/core/genericAccess.inp#L135)

So I assume that the quotation marks in the `\directlua` command are expanded to "smart quotes" before the Lua code can be executed.

- Is this assumption right?
- Is there anything I can do about it?
- Or do I have to accept and document the incompatibility?

Comment: "Ninja'd" :) https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367913

Comment: See my answer here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/367922/2388. You need to ensure that tex.sprint uses a "safe" catcode table.

Comment: I voted to close this because it has been answered in the other question (so it's not an actual "duplicate" of a previous question ...)