# Error in listings file when combined with \lstset and unicode-math package

Tags: listings, luatex, unicode-math

Today, I wanted to compile a document that worked flawlessly earlier that year. However, LuaLaTex was complaining about some code lines inside of a C++ listing. I boiled the problem down to the following minimal example:

test.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\scriptsize}
\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting{test.cpp}
\end{document}
```

test.cpp:

```
int main()
{
  return (int)(-1.l);
}
```

If I compile with `lualatex test.tex` I get the following :

```
(./test.cpp                                                                                                                                
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
global 
l.3   return (int)(-1.l
                     );
?
```

If I uncomment the unicode-math package or the lstset command or use xelatex, it compiles just fine. What's wrong?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) What is your `lualatex --version`? It works fine for me :/

Comment: I can reproduce the problem on MikTeX's LuaLaTeX 1.07.0 (Win 10). An even shorter MWE is `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\scriptsize}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
-
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}`

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik it fails with texlive 2018 pretest

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I'm using LuaTeX, Version 1.0.4 (TeX Live 2017/Arch Linux).

Comment: What's wrong? No idea :) https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/454

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It works if you make sure that scriptsize math is set up before listings starts:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\scriptsize}

\begin{document}
\sbox0{\scriptsize $x$}
\lstinputlisting{test.cpp}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This walks, swims and quacks like a bug. Any idea what is to blame here? The minus seems to be the problematic character here. But using XeLaTeX solves the issue and so does not loading `unicode-math`.

Comment: @moewe see Ulrike's answer

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that fontspec/unicode-math reads font dimens with luacode. And while catcodes in the tex code are frozen when the code is read the first time this is not true for values you get from directlua: there the catcode settings of the execution time matters. So when trying to setup the font in the middle of lstlisting (which activates all chars) things explodes.

A similar problem was here [Who's at fault with this error concerning csquotes and LuaLaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367913/whos-at-fault-with-this-error-concerning-csquotes-and-lualatex)

The problem can be resolved by explicitly setting the catcode table in the first argument of tex.sprint when reading the dimens. I added this suggestion to the github tracker of unicode-math.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\RequirePackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
local latexcatcodetable = luatexbase.registernumber("catcodetable@latex")
function fontspec.mathfontdimen(fnt, str)
    local mathdimens = luaotfload.aux.get_math_dimension(fnt, str)
    if mathdimens then
        tex.sprint(latexcatcodetable,mathdimens)
        tex.sprint(latexcatcodetable,"sp")
    else
        tex.sprint(latexcatcodetable,"0pt")
    end
end
\end{luacode}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{basicstyle=\scriptsize}
\begin{document}


\begin{lstlisting}
-
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you can use  `latex` defined as `local latex = luatexbase.registernumber("catcodetable@latex")` instead of `luatexbase.catcodetables.latex` then you don't need `luatexbase` (or `luacode`) packages.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I edited the answer (and I need luacode for the example ...)

Comment: I find it's usually simpler to use `\directlua` directly

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Hm. yes. But I normally avoid directlua for more than three lines -- I'm getting to easily confused when I want to comment parts of the code.

Comment: Ohhhh of course. This isn’t the first bug like this to have reared its head. Thanks!

Comment: @WillRobertson yes, I had yesterday directly the impression I had seen something like this already ;-). But it made me aware that I had never thought about the catcodes of outputs from e.g. \the\fontdimen.